# Confirm document existance before retrieving or doing multiple queries

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to retrieve one BsonDocument from a collection using user input. I already found a straightforward way to do this:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", name);
var doc = await myCollection.Find(filter).SingleAsync();
```

This works fine, but when there's no match, it throws an `System.InvalidOperationException` at the `SingleAsync` method:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorExtensions.SingleAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursor`1 cursor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.SingleAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyProgram.Main.Test() in D:\MyProgram\Main.cs:line 22
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I figured I could catch this exception everytime it happens, but is that the right way to do it? I can check for existance using `AnyAsync` too, but that would involve doing 2 separate queries which might hurt database performance.

What would be the right way to do so?

Comment: You may want to try a SingleOrDefaultAsync(), Single() is designed to fire in the case of no entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `SingleAsync()` is that `SingleAsync` will deliberately throw an error if it does not find exactly 1 result. The way around that is to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. `FirstOrDefault` will return exactly 1 result if there is 1 result, or the first result if there are multiple, or `null` if it couldn't get anything.